# java.lang.ArrayStoreException with new JPanel

Tags: java, swing, exception, jpanel

I have a problem:

```
public static JPanel regNewBodyPart(int i, int x, int y){

    //System.out.println(i);

    body[i] = new SnakeBlock();
    JPanel bp = body[i];
    //bp.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    bp.setBounds(x, y, 20, 20);
    bp.setVisible(true);
    registeredBodyParts++;

    return(bp);

}
```

Throws an `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`, when I change

`body[i] = new SnakeBlock();` to `body[i] = new Block();` does not.

I dont what I've done false..

The `SnakeBlock()` and `Block()` classes are similar!

SnakeBlock / Block:

```
public class Block /* /SnakeBlock */ extends JPanel{

    public Block() /* /SnakeBlock */{

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        super.paintComponent(g);    
    } 
}
```

Comment: How is the array `body` defined?

Comment: What type is your `body` variable?

Comment: `public static JPanel[] body;`

`public Schlange(){
  body = new Block[3600];   
 }`

Comment: similar means that they are the same classes except for the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an ArrayStoreException:

```
Object x[] = new String[3];
x[0] = new Integer(0);
```

To avoid this exception, define the `body` array as the appropriate data type, for example:

```
JPanel[] body = new JPanel[n];
```

Comment: I'm sure both classes `extends JPanel`

Comment: Sure, but your comment above initalizes the array as being of type `Block`, and `Block` and `SnakeBlock` are different classes